# Add button to StackNavigator header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How to add a third button to the header? I want to create something like this

[image]

I added the the left and the right components with this code:

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: AppDrawer,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={35}
                         onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') } />,
      headerRight: <HeaderUserInformation />,

    })
  },
```

How can I add the eath component in the shown position? I tried this but I got an error

```
headerRight: 
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <HeaderUserInformation />
      <earthComponent />
      </View>
```

Comment: Add the error message to your question please.

Comment: try just `header` with `headerLeft` and `headerRight`. If this doesn't work try passing a view (which has two of the buttons) as one of the headers .